# ActionController::UnknownFormat / Missing template error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, loops

I am getting a "template missing error" on a .js.erb file, everything i've read says to add a respond_to which I did below but it's still not seeing my create.js.erb file, any ideas?

```
def create
  @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
  @message = @conversation.messages.build(message_params)
  @message.user_id = current_user.id
  @message.save!

  @path = conversation_path(@conversation)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Comment: can you please post the log trace

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have `create.js.erb` file in `app/views/:controller_name/`

If not create one at `app/views/:controller_name/`

Comment: negative, create.js.erb exists in the messages view, the above controller action is from MessagesController

Comment: @whataboutme1 can you please post the log

Comment: you want the server log?

Comment: @whataboutme1 It will help to find exact problem